# is port not common for all the docker networks?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have created two docker networks

1. chnetwork

   ```
    docker network create --subnet=172.19.0.0/16 chnetwork
   ```
2. Internal-network

   ```
    docker network  create --internal --subnet 10.1.1.0/24 internal-network
   ```

while create docker container I use **chnetwork**,

```
docker run -it -d --name containerone -h www.cone.net -v /var/www/html -p 3006:80 --net chnetwork --ip 172.19.0.40 --privileged magento
```

later I have changed to **Internal-network** and disconnect container from **chnetwork**

```
docker network connect internal-network containerone
docker network disconnect chnetwork containerone
```

now the problem is **docker ps** command does not display port of that container, I mean port is not accessible in **internal-network**.

when I change network to **chnetwork** that time only **docker ps** display ports. what I need to do for port is accessible in all the docker networks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be the behavior of internal networking. Since the only network attached to the container is an internal network which doesn't permit external traffic, the container becomes isolated by design. To publish a port, you need the container to be attached to a non-internal bridged network. And as soon as you connect a non-internal bridged network to the container, you will see the published port reappear.