# Restrict docker container access to the host LAN but not to internet

Tags: docker, networking

I've been wondering on how the following scenario could be accomplished **only using docker networks** (no iptables or anything that has to be done on the host).

I want to run a docker container with **access only to the host's LAN, but no access to the internet at all**.

The --internal will restrict access of the container outside the docker network, so won't fit this situation.
And docker's ***host*** network will only give the container access to the host, but not to the host's LAN.

Any idea on how can this be accomplished without using host-based solutions (like using iptables on the host)?

Thanks !

Comment: have you considered putting your container inside another container? the parent container could provide a re-usable way to setup network restrictions.

Comment: Actually, this looks relevant: [Restrict Internet Access - Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42336592/5257399)