# How to restrict Docker container access to other containers and to the internet (expose port only for host)?

Tags: docker, docker-network

How to create the Docker network so that the container expose ports only for the host and have no access to the internet and to the other containers?

I found the solution for [restricting access to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913757/restrict-internet-access-docker-container), but it allows containers to interact with each other.

Comment: To limit access between containers, use Docker Compose with custom networks. Add containers to the networks of other containers they need to see.

Comment: In the example you linked, containers can only communicate with containers in the same network. If you write docker-compose with 1 network and 1 container it will solve your problem.