# "This node is not a swarm manager" error, but I'm not using docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For testing our escrow build, I'm attempting to set up a docker network that's isolated from the host and from the outside world.

I've got the following `docker-compose.yml` (inspired by [this forum post](https://forums.docker.com/t/internal-network-between-containers-without-external-network-access/41751/9)):

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:2.8.23"
    networks:
      - isolated

  # ... more services (TODO)

networks:
  isolated:
    driver: overlay
    internal: true
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d`; it creates the network, but then fails to create the containers, reporting the following:

> ERROR: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.

**But I'm not using docker swarm, nor do I want to.**

If I remove the `services:` stanza from the file, it brings up the network without the error. It warns that the network is unused (obviously).

If I remove the `services/redis/networks` stanza, it brings up the container correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51964169/8446), which uses `driver: bridge` for the network, but that still allows access to the host.

---

- Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
- docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have specified the network driver to be `overlay`.

The [overlay network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) very much depends on swarm mode and can effectively be considered to be a swarm mode component.

Instead, you should choose a driver that is a local scope driver rather than a swarm scope driver.

The driver you should use is the `bridge` driver. The [bridge network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) is not part of swarm mode and does not depend on swarm mode being active to utilize it.

Since you are using docker-compose, you can just leave the specific driver out entirely, and it will choose the appropriate driver for you. I would recommend removing the `driver: overlay` line out completely and leaving the rest of the file as-is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:2.8.23"
    networks:
      - isolated

  # ... more services (TODO)

networks:
  isolated:
    internal: true
```

Comment: This is what I did in the end, but it leaves the container able to access the host. I can live with that, I guess, but I'd prefer a completely isolated network...

Comment: Take a look at the macvlan driver too.

Comment: I am getting the same error while trying to create --attachable overlay network for standalone container

Comment: @GunjanShah if you want to use any swarm features, including attachable overlay networks, you'll need to make the node be a part of a swarm.

Comment: @programmerq, I was referring documents on docker website : https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/. The docs for overlay network for standalone container is really confusing. They have not clearly mentioned that the node must needs to be swarm resource where we can create attachable overlay network. Even I have added new question on this query. You can add more details there if you don't mind : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134199/error-while-creating-overlay-network-for-standalone-containers