# Error while creating overlay network for standalone containers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

As per the Docker documentation, overlay network is automatically getting created when we initialise docker swarm. But we can not use that network for individual docker container which not part of swarm resource. So, we need to create overlay network with "--attachable" flag.

I tried to create attachable overlay network but I am getting following error :

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable my-attachable-overlay 
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

Do we need to run this command on swarm manager ? Can't we use it directly on low weight container like boot2docker without initialising docker swarm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swarm scoped overlay network driver does indeed require swarm. If you have a single node, you only need to do `docker swarm init` and then you can create a swarm scoped network. If you are getting this error on a swarm worker node, then you just need to create the network on a manager in the swarm and then it can be used on the worker nodes in that swarm.

The whole purpose of the overlay network driver is to enable container-to-container communication between multiple nodes in a swarm. It is not necessary to use the overlay network driver in a single node where you do not intend to use any other swarm features nor communicate with containers on other nodes. Use a local scoped network driver instead like `bridge`.