# No internet inside docker container in created network

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm having trouble with internet inside my docker. I have internet connection in a default network, but I don't have it in my created network. I've checked it by trying to ping google.com. I have created the network like this

> network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet123

Any ideas on this? How can I get access to the internet?

Comment: Are you sure that your 172.18.0.0 has internet connection?

Comment: @mulg0r I've said that I don't have it in this network at all. So that's what the question is about.

Comment: In this case is not a docker-network problem, but is a problem of your connectivity internet in your host. First, solve that and then tell me in which interface in your host do you have internet to face docker-network problem

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this answer, if you create your network like this, it should have the internet connection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42336592/332451

If you create the network with the `--internal` switch, it'd have become a network without a route to the internet.

Comment: Well it doesn't solve the issue. By the way, there's no internet connection in any network that I create manually.