# Two containers in a gCloud VM, one isolated from the internet

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I have two containers. Container A should have no internet access and only be able to communicate with Container B. Container B should be something like a "communicator". I want to do REST API calls from Container B to Container A.

How can I "connect" both containers, but make sure A can't communicate to the outside world?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42336592/12232507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create internal only network.

   ```
   docker network create --internal --subnet 10.1.1.0/24 no-internet
   ```
2. Run container A attached to internal network.

   ```
   docker run --network=no-internet -d --name containerA <image A>
   ```
3. Run container B in default network, already exposed to the internet.

   ```
   docker run -d --name containerB <image B>
   ```
4. Connect container B to internal network to communicate with container A.

   ```
   docker network connect no-internet containerB
   ```
5. Curl container A from container B either by its name or IP address.

Now container A is isolated in internal network. Container B connected to both internal and default network and can communicate both with container A and outside world.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have tagged this ticket with google-cloud-platform I am assuming your question is with reference to GKE (though this will also apply to kubernetes in general):

You can solve your problem using network policies object. You can create network policies to manage traffic between two pods and to outside world:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
        except:
        - 172.17.1.0/24
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          project: myproject
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: frontend
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5978
```

see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Comment: No, i don't use kubernetes, can i use the without it anyway?

Comment: yes, I think your use-case is similar to the use-case discussed in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913757/restrict-internet-access-docker-container