# Rest-Api call to Jenkins always throws 401

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking

i try to do a api call to Jenkins. The Jenkins is stored in a Docker container on a GCloud VM and got no internet connection (Done with a docker network like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913757/restrict-internet-access-docker-container/42336592#42336592)).
If i test this on my local machine, it works perfectly.

**My CURL to the rest API:**

```
docker exec jenkins curl -X GET localhost:8080 -u USER:PASS
```

**The result:**

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Invalid password/token for user: USER</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /. Reason:
<pre>    Invalid password/token for user: admin</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
100   373  100   373    0     0   1703      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1703
```

Comment: Try to restart user/pass and update request.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi what do you mean with restart?

Comment: Re-run request to jenkins

Comment: I did several times