# Allow Docker container to talk to host only

Tags: docker, networking, containers

Is there a way to disallow all traffic in Docker container except for traffic from/to the host?

For security reasons, I do not want container to be able to connect to the internet, or scan of other devices on the main network. Defining specific ports host and container can talk trough would be ideal.

#### Possible example

```
Allow
host(192.168.0.2:7777) <----> container(192.168.5.1:6666)

Disallow
everything else
```

#### My attempt

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.5.0/24 br0
docker run -it --net=br0 --rm --name ubuntutest robertxie/ubuntu-nettools:latest
```

which assigns IP 192.168.5.2 to the container, but it does also allow connection to the internet and other devices

Comment: Your problem may be  similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913757/restrict-internet-access-docker-container)

Comment: using --internal flag blocked traffic with host as well as the access to the internet