# How to restrict docker network access between containers in same network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My situation is as follows:
I have traefik as http proxy for multiple webs. And I have a network, let's call it a "proxy-net" that links together traefik with these webs.
So this network is obviously required to each web to be proxied by traefik. Issue I have is that containers of those webs can connect to each other via this "proxy-net" network.
How do I restrict that? How to allow each web to connect to traefik but restrict connection between other containers in this same network?
And also keeping each web to have access to internet (for npm, composer, apis etc.)? Cause I saw some possibilities to add dns or similar stuff to containers which didn't work with my issue here.

I tried these, no luck:
https://sodocumentation.net/docker/topic/6331/restricting-container-network-access
[Restrict Internet Access - Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913757/restrict-internet-access-docker-container)