# Docker Container expose port, but don't have access to internet, only to host machine

Tags: docker, networking

I want the container to make the port available outside (ngnix), but I don't want to have internet access, only to the machine it is on. How to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict Internet Access - Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913757/restrict-internet-access-docker-container). [Host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) has nothing to do with internet access it's about not isolating a container's network stack from the host's which is the default behavior of docker. Also be aware that host networking is only supported on Linux, so not on Windows or Mac.